# How do you install bazel using bazelisk

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, installation, bazel

Or better yet, how do you install bazel at all. I have been using cd to get into a folder on my desktop, then I used `git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk` and then? What am I supposed to do now, honestly I didn't find any real instruction for this, I have many folder in there now, am I supposed to run a special file like bazelisk.py now? Or like build it? Was I supposed to clone the github repository in a special location? As mentioned I just choose a folder on my desktop, but I added the path to my Path enviromental variable, I added `C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\bazel` and `C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\bazel\bazelisk` because I wasn't sure how far I should go. So if anybody could show me how to install bazel at all I would be thankful, I just need it for a python project, I am using python 3.6.2 and I am on windows 10. I don't know what to do now because the installation steps I've read only go as far as saying to git clone the repository, but when I enter cmd and type `bazel` or `bazel help` cmd can not find the command.

Answer (score 36):

From Official Bazel Documentation

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/blob/master/README.md ->

Bazelisk is a wrapper for Bazel written in Go. It automatically picks a good version of Bazel given your current working directory, downloads it from the official server (if required) and then transparently passes through all command-line arguments to the real Bazel binary. You can call it just like you would call Bazel.

**Steps to Installing Bazelisk in Linux/Mac/Windows**

Below steps show installation of bazelisk v1.8.1, but you can install any desired version from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases using same steps

**Steps for Bazelisk Linux Install**

```
> wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.8.1/bazelisk-linux-amd64
> chmod +x bazelisk-linux-amd64
> sudo mv bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel
     
# make sure you get the binary available in $PATH
> which bazel
bazel is /usr/local/bin/bazel
```

**Steps for Bazelisk Mac Install**

```
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.8.1/bazelisk-darwin-amd64
chmod +x bazelisk-darwin-amd64
sudo mv bazelisk-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel
```

**Steps for Bazelisk Windows Install**

Download and install Bazelisk windows binary from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases

**How to use Bazelisk and set desired Bazel version**

- If the environment variable `USE_BAZEL_VERSION` is set, it will use the
  version specified in the value.
- Otherwise, if a `.bazeliskrc` file exists in the workspace root and
  contains the USE_BAZEL_VERSION variable, this version will be used.
- Otherwise, if a `.bazelversion` file exists in the current directory or
  recursively any parent directory, it will read the file and use the
  version specified in it.
- Otherwise it will use the official latest Bazel release.

**Common issues you might face**

- When bazel version is updated in `WORKSPACE` file and if you are unable to see bazel version update after `bazel version` call
- Then try removing old bazel binary `/usr/local/bin/bazel` and again do bazelisk installation mentioned above.

Comment: Anyone figured out how to get bash completion working using this approach?
https://bazel.build/install/completion

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Windows I will describe the Windows way of doing it (it is also similar on other platforms)

Download a prebuild version of `bazelisk.exe`. You can find prebuilt versions [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases). For instance, [v1.7.4](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.7.4/bazelisk-windows-amd64.exe). Then rename `bazelisk-windows-amd64.exe` to `bazelisk.exe` and add it to your `PATH` environment variable. When you open now a PowerShell and type `bazelisk info` you should see some output.

`bazelisk` is only a wrapper around `bazel` which means you have still to setup everything to make Bazel working on your system. `bazelisk` just redirects all commands to Bazel. `bazelisk` just cares about which version of Bazel is used (e.g. you can define in a `.bazelversion` file wich version of Bazel should be used). I suggest you to follow the instructions listed [here](https://bazel.build/install/windows) that describe what needs to be done to get Bazel working on Windows (for instance installing MSYS2 makes sense).

Comment: hmh, I think I have done everything the site tells me to do. I do have MSYS2 and I ran the command I was supposed to run after installing parts of visual studio. Then instead of a bazel version I downloaded the prebuilt bazelisk file and added it to my PATH environment variable. You said I still have to install Java Runtime Environment but I did what the side said and it says I am done. I mean what you explained me works, I can run bazelisk commands now, but no bazel commands, are bazel commands just bazelisk commands because I installed bazelisk or what do I have to do now?

Comment: bazelisk just redirects all commands to Bazel - bazelisk just cares about which version of bazel is used (e.g. you can define in a `.bazelversion` file wich version of Bazel should be used)

Comment: So I can f.ex. just use bazelisk build instead of bazel build or something? Cool but as mentioned, you told me that I still have to install stuff like Java Runtime Environment, where is that mentioned on the website you sent?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. JRE is not needed - seems that JRE is not needed since it is shipped with OpenJDK - Java SE Development Kit 11 (JDK) for Windows x64 is needed if you want to make use of java rules.

Comment: Well I guess I have another problem. I want to use tensorflow, but I can not use its pip package, so I want to build tensorflow from source. I followed a guide and it told me to download bazel. When I use cd to get into the tensorflow folder, then I use `python ./configure.py` I get the message `Cannot find bazel. Please install bazel.`