# How to install Bazel on Linux?

Tags: bazel

I tried to install bazel on a linux system by executing the following commands:

```
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk/releases/download/v1.8.1/bazelisk-linux-amd64
chmod +x bazelisk-linux-amd64
sudo mv bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel
```

The steps are from this post: [How do you install bazel using bazelisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656165/how-do-you-install-bazel-using-bazelisk)

But when I use bazel to build a program, it's still complaining it couldn't find bazel. Did I missing anything in the steps? Thanks!

Comment: How do you call it? Is the program even in your `$PATH`?

Comment: How do you try to use `bazel` to build? Do you just type `bazel build ...` and  how does it fail? Could it be as trivial as you just put it somewhere (`/usr/local/bin/`) which is not in your `PATH`?

Comment: I added the path to $PATH. The problem is I don't know whether I need to do anything further with bazelisk-linux-amd64 as in my directory I have bazelisk-linux-amd64 instead of bazel.

Comment: In what directory? `mv bazelisk-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/bazel` move the `bazelisk-linux-amd64` into `/usr/local/bin/` named `bazel`. As long as `/usr/local/bin/` is in your `PATH` you can call `bazel` to run `bazelisk` and have it get / wrap bazel call.